# Join list of dict with a dict in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to know if exists a more elegant way to join a list of dictionary with another dictionary.

```
list1 = list()
list1.append({"ip": '12.12.12.12', 'code': '123'})
list1.append({"ip": '12.12.12.11', 'code': '345'})    
dict2 = {"mask": "255.255.255.255"}            
nlist = list()
for dict1 in list1:                
    dict1.update(dict2)
    nlist.append(dict1)        
print nlist
```

this is the expected output:

```
[{'ip': '12.12.12.12', 'code': '123', 'mask': '255.255.255.255'}, 
{'ip': '12.12.12.11', 'code': '345', 'mask': '255.255.255.255'}]
```

Comment: is this the expected output or the output which you are getting?

Comment: That's the expected result, I wonder if you can improve the code

Comment: Do you desire the side-effect that the dictionaries in `list1` are updated _and_ added to `nlist`, i.e. both lists refer to the same dictionaries? Or were you hoping for new copies of the dicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has the side-effect that it updates the same instance of each dictionary object, resulting in both `list1` and `nlist` referring to the same dictionary objects. After execution of your code:

```
>>> list1
[{'ip': '12.12.12.12', 'code': '123', 'mask': '255.255.255.255'}, {'ip': '12.12.12.11', 'code': '345', 'mask': '255.255.255.255'}]
>>> nlist
[{'ip': '12.12.12.12', 'code': '123', 'mask': '255.255.255.255'}, {'ip': '12.12.12.11', 'code': '345', 'mask': '255.255.255.255'}
>>> [list1[i] is nlist[i] for i in range(len(list1))]
[True, True]
>>> list1[0]['newkey'] = 'value'
>>> list1[0]
{'ip': '12.12.12.12', 'code': '123', 'mask': '255.255.255.255', 'newkey': 'value'}
>>> nlist[0]
{'ip': '12.12.12.12', 'code': '123', 'mask': '255.255.255.255', 'newkey': 'value'}
```

The above shows that the dicts are the same, and so any update is reflected in both lists.

If you simply wanted to update all the dictionaries in `list1`, do this:

```
dict2 = {"mask": "255.255.255.255"}
for d in list1:
    d.update(dict2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go for list comprehension which looks little simpler. Not much of a difference though.

```
list1 = list()  
list1.append({"ip": '12.12.12.12', 'code': '123'})  
list1.append({"ip": '12.12.12.11', 'code': '345'})   
dict2 = {"mask": "255.255.255.255"}  
[ _dict.update(dict2) for _dict in list1]  
print list1  

Output: [{'ip': '12.12.12.12', 'code': '123', 'mask': '255.255.255.255'}, {'ip': '12.12.12.11', 'code': '345', 'mask': '255.255.255.255'}]
```

Comment: Not much difference? After this statement `list1` is `[None, None]` (because `dict.update()` returns none. That's quite different to the expected output.